# How can I create an External Catalog Table in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-calcite, flink-sql

I tried to create and ExternalCatalog to use in Apache Flink Table. I created and added to the Flink table environment (here the official [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/common.html#register-an-external-catalog)). For some reason, the only external table present in the 'catalog', it is not found during the scan. What I missed in the code above?

```
  val catalogName = s"externalCatalog$fileNumber"
  val ec: ExternalCatalog = getExternalCatalog(catalogName, 1, tableEnv)
  tableEnv.registerExternalCatalog(catalogName, ec)
  val s1: Table = tableEnv.scan("S_EXT")

  def getExternalCatalog(catalogName: String, fileNumber: Int, tableEnv: BatchTableEnvironment): ExternalCatalog = {
    val cat = new InMemoryExternalCatalog(catalogName)
    // external Catalog table
    val externalCatalogTableS = getExternalCatalogTable("S")
    // add external Catalog table
    cat.createTable("S_EXT", externalCatalogTableS, ignoreIfExists = false)
    cat
  }

  private def getExternalCatalogTable(fileName: String): ExternalCatalogTable = {
    // connector descriptor
    val connectorDescriptor = new FileSystem()
    connectorDescriptor.path(getFilePath(fileNumber, fileName))
    // format
    val fd = new Csv()
    fd.field("X", Types.STRING)
    fd.field("Y", Types.STRING)
    fd.fieldDelimiter(",")
    // statistic
    val statistics = new Statistics()
    statistics.rowCount(0)
    // metadata
    val md = new Metadata()
    ExternalCatalogTable.builder(connectorDescriptor)
      .withFormat(fd)
      .withStatistics(statistics)
      .withMetadata(md)
      .asTableSource()
  }
```

The example above is part of this [test file in git](https://github.com/srapisarda/stypes-flink/blob/feature/sql/src/test/scala/uk/ac/bbk/dcs/stypes/flink/CalciteEmptyConsistencyTest.scala).

Comment: The reason for creating an ExternalCatalog is to provide Statistics for each table present in the 'Catalog'. This reason was explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101174/why-does-flink-sql-use-a-cardinality-estimate-of-100-rows-for-all-tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a namespace issue. Tables in external catalogs are identified by a list of names of the catalog, (potentially schemas,) and finally the table name.

In your example, the following should work:

```
val s1: Table = tableEnv.scan("externalCatalog1", "S_EXT")
```

You can have a look at the [ExternalCatalogTest](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/test/scala/org/apache/flink/table/api/ExternalCatalogTest.scala) to see how external catalogs can be used.

Comment: Yes, it works but only if I don't include the statistics in the table which are necessary for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101174/why-does-flink-sql-use-a-cardinality-estimate-of-100-rows-for-all-tables

Is it possible to use the object ***statistic*** in an external catalog table?

This part of the error returned: 

Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.BatchTableSourceFactory' in
the classpath.

Reason: 
The matching factory 'org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvBatchTableSourceFactory' doesn't support 'statistics.row-count'.
...

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the specific `CsvBatchTableSourceFactory`. You might want to fork and extend it to support statistics.