# Why does Apache Calcite estimates 100 rows for all tables a query contains?

Tags: csv, relational-algebra, sql-optimization, apache-calcite

I recently tried to execute a query in Apache Calcite using three CSV files as tables

- TTLA_ONE contains 59 rows
- TTLR_ONE contains 61390 rows
- EMPTY_T  contains 0 rows

This is the query which is executed:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM 
FROM TTLA_ONE A 
INNER JOIN TTLR_ONE B1 ON A.X = B1.X
INNER JOIN TTLR_ONE B2 ON B2.X = B1.X
INNER JOIN EMPTY_T C1 ON C1.X = B2.Y
INNER JOIN EMPTY_T C2 ON C2.X = C2.X
```

The result of the query is always zero because we are joining with an empty table. 
The plan obtained is:

```
EnumerableAggregate(group=[{}], NUM=[COUNT()])
  EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($1, $4)], joinType=[inner])
    EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner])
      EnumerableInterpreter
        BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLA_ONE]])
      EnumerableCalc(expr#0..1=[{inputs}], X=[$t0])
        EnumerableInterpreter
          BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLR_ONE]])
    EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($1, $3)], joinType=[inner])
      EnumerableJoin(condition=[true], joinType=[inner])
        EnumerableCalc(expr#0=[{inputs}], expr#1=[IS NOT NULL($t0)], X=[$t0], $condition=[$t1])
          EnumerableInterpreter
            BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, EMPTY_T]])
        EnumerableInterpreter
          BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, EMPTY_T]])
      EnumerableInterpreter
        BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLR_ONE]])
```

It is possible to note that the empty tables are used in the plan at the very end.

I add an example on this [test code](https://github.com/srapisarda/stypes-flink/blob/feature/sql/src/test/scala/uk/ac/bbk/dcs/stypes/flink/CalciteSQLTest.scala).

I dig more into the code and I switched on the log to debug and I have seen that all the tables rows are estimated as 100, but this is not true.

Below, It is possible to find the plan estimation with the logs set in debug mode:

```
  EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($1, $4)], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 3.0375E7, cumulative cost = {3.075002214917643E7 rows, 950.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26284
EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($0, $1)], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 1500.0, cumulative cost = {2260.517018598809 rows, 400.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26267
  EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26260
    BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLA_ONE]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.01 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 7789
  EnumerableCalc(expr#0..1=[{inputs}], X=[$t0]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {150.0 rows, 350.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26290
    EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26263
      BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLR_ONE]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.01 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 7791
EnumerableJoin(condition=[=($1, $3)], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 135000.0, cumulative cost = {226790.8015771949 rows, 550.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26282
  EnumerableJoin(condition=[true], joinType=[inner]): rowcount = 9000.0, cumulative cost = {9695.982870329724 rows, 500.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26277
    EnumerableCalc(expr#0=[{inputs}], expr#1=[IS NOT NULL($t0)], X=[$t0], $condition=[$t1]): rowcount = 90.0, cumulative cost = {140.0 rows, 450.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26288
      EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26270
        BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, EMPTY_T]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.01 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 7787
    EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26275
      BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, EMPTY_T]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.01 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 7787
  EnumerableInterpreter: rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {50.0 rows, 50.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 26280
    BindableTableScan(table=[[STYPES, TTLR_ONE]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.01 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 7791
```

We can definitely see that for each table the estimation is always 100 `rowcount = 100.0`.

The query is executed correctly but the plan is not optimised. Does anyone know why the table statistics are not correctly evaluated?

Comment: How is this different from your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54101174/3404097?

Comment: yes, I suppose it is the same problem Flink inherited by using apache Calcite. That was generating a new question and an issue as well  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278508/how-can-i-create-an-external-catalog-table-in-apache-flink

Comment: In this example, it is used just Apache Calcite.

Comment: why is this tagged `relational-algebra`?

Comment: Because each logical execution plan is created by using [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). Afterwards, in between all the possible plans obtained, it is chosen the one which has minimal cost. For sure the problem is not in the relational algebra because in the specific the estimated cardinality of rows of each relation it is always the same therefore the cost estimation is fake.

Comment: "Because each logical execution plan is created by using relational algebra." Not it isn't; that wikipedia page says "theoretical foundation", not 'execution plan'. I see no RA anywhere in your q. `EnumerableJoin` is not a RA operator. I'm pointing this out to help you: if you're asking about something low level in SQL, then thinking RA has something to do with it will only confuse you.

Comment: @AntC http://calcite.apache.org/docs/algebra.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the class `CsvTable` it is necessary to override the  `getStatistic` property method, by doing something like this:

```
 private Statistic statistic;
 // todo: assign statistics  

  @Override
  public Statistic getStatistic() {
    return statistic;
  }
```

maybe pass these statistics from the constructor or inject some object which generates them.

At the moment it returns just `Statistics.UNKNOWN` which is in the superclass implementation  AbstractTable`.
Of course without statistics, the estimated cost for the plan is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here seems to be the same as for questions already linked from comments.

> Flink does not (yet) reorder joins
>
> In the current version (1.7.1, Jan 2019), ... Calcite uses its default value which is 100.

So the execution plan is not looking for tables with zero rows. In particular, I suspect from those answers that even if you re-ordered the tables in the `FROM` clause, it still wouldn't notice.

In general, SQL optimisation is driven by the availability of indexes as much as by cardinality of the tables.

> The only way to inject cardinality estimates for tables is via an `ExternalCatalog`.

Are you doing that?

If you're loading these tables as CSV files, are you declaring keys and indexes, and other stuff needed for the catalog?

It sounds like Calcite is not a mature product. If you're looking for a testbed to examine SQL optimisations/query plan, use a different product.

Comment: While it's true that Calcite has room to improve, it's also been around for roughly 7 years and sees pretty widespread usage. That said, for any non-trivial use of Calcite, there will be some work to do to get it perform at it's best. We're happy to take any contributions for improvement! (Disclaimer: member of  the Calcite PMC.)

Comment: The implementation for the `ExternalCatalog`  in apache Flink was done but it was found an issue with the specific `CsvBatchTableSourceFactory` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278508/how-can-i-create-an-external-catalog-table-in-apache-flink. I am looking into the problem https://github.com/srapisarda/flink/commit/d6e4092bfba167622994f04979e2a97f679db706